# Formatted Drive Permissions - GNOME Disk Utility

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

**Preface**

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.(x), and I'd formatted a flash drive using the GNOME Disk Utility as Ext4. I've done this many times before on many different operating systems, but every now and again encounter this issue. Opening the newly formatted disk via the file manager will not allow me options to create folders or files or documents. (Essentially, I don't have permissions.) I solved this issue using `sudo chown schyken:root /media/schyken/drive/`

**Question**

Though I'm aware of a solution, I'm not quite sure what the cause of this is. Does anyone know about this issue, or of any bugs filed about it? Has anyone experienced this as well? If so, is there a way to prevent this from occuring in the future?

Comment: I have found that all sorts of these kind of bugs occur when the device in question is a flash stick. It is very strange indeed.